# WordPress Plugin - Export string data to downloadable txt fie

Tags: php, wordpress

Part of a new WordPress plugin I'm creating is that i would like to have an option to download a txt file that contains the data from a basic string value.

The function for this particular part is:

```html
function get_page_links()
 {
  $pages = get_pages( 'post_status=publish' );
  foreach ( $pages as $page )
   {
    $pagetitle = $page->post_title;
    $pagelink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
    echo "{$pagetitle}";
    echo "\n";
    echo "{$pagelink}";
   }
 }
```

I would like to have a txt fie generated and the {$pagelink} string added to the txt file (in the loop to get all the pagelinks within the string) and then have it available to download.

I have tried adding the following code to the function, but it does not seem to do anything at all...

```
    $file = 'file.txt';
    $data = '{$pagelink}';
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_put_contents` would create a file if non-existent, and write the content to it, not append, just so you know. Calling it in a loop would cause it to constantly overwrite the link you have written until your loop ends, and you will end up with just the last link in your file.

The following code would write all links in a file, with one link in each line. Calling this function again will overwrite the file still with all the links, so that it would update if you have deleted a page or created a new one.

```
function get_page_links()
{
        $pages = get_pages( 'post_status=publish' );
        // use the code below if your making a plugin
        // this will be found on:
        // path/to/yourplugin/links.txt
        $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'links.txt';

        // use the code below if you're making a theme
        // this will be found on:
        // path/to/yourtheme/links.txt
        // $file = get_template_directory() . '/links.txt' 

        $n_handle_file = fopen($file,'w');
        foreach ( $pages as $page )
            {
                $pagetitle = $page->post_title;
                $pagelink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
                echo "{$pagetitle}";
                echo "\n";
                echo "{$pagelink}";
                fprintf($n_handle_file, "%s\n", $pagelink);
            }
         fclose($n_handle_file);
    }
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this, it works perfectly and is now writing the links list to the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems from your code:
1) The line below in the loop is not appending to the previous value of $pagelink
   $pagelink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
   It should be changed to
   $pagelink .= get_permalink( $page->ID );
2) Or there might be file writing privilege problem
   Try changing the line 
   $file = 'file.txt'; to
   $file = plugin_dir_path(**FILE**) . 'file.txt';

Please share the full code